# How do I rotate a CAGradientLayer by 180 degrees?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-animation

I have created a `CAGradientLayer` for my custom `UIButton`s.  The code for creating it is as follows:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

gradient.frame = btn.bounds;
gradient.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
locations=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: LOC_0, LOC_5, LOC_51,LOC_1, nil]; 
[gradient setLocations:locations];
colorNext=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(id) G3_rgb1, (id) G3_rgb2, (id) G3_rgb3, (id) G3_rgb4, nil]; 
gradient.colors = colorNext;

[btn.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

My question is: on the press of the button I need to change the gradient view of the button by 180 degrees, how should I do this?

Answer (score 18):

You can also change the start and end points of your gradient.  The default startPoint is `{0.5, 0.0}`. The default endPoint is `{0.5, 1.0}`.  Flip those to make your gradient go the other way.

```
[gradient setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)];
[gradient setEndPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0)];
```

Flip them back to display normally.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you maintain a pointer to the gradient layer, you should be able to reverse the gradient color ordering by providing an inverted set of locations:

```
NSArray *newLocations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(1.0 - [LOC_0 floatValue])], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(1.0 - [LOC_5 floatValue])], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(1.0 - [LOC_51 floatValue])], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(1.0 - [LOC_1 floatValue])], nil]; 
[gradient setLocations:newLocations];
[newLocations release];

[gradient setNeedsDisplay];
```

(this would be cleaner if you had the float values for LOC_0, etc.)

I'm not sure if the `-setNeedsDisplay` is required, but it often is for content changes in a layer.

That said, Vanya's solution of applying a rotational transform may be the quickest way to achieve this effect.

As a comment, hopefully you have a `[locations release]` and `[colorNext release]` somewhere later in your code, otherwise you'll be leaking the locations and color arrays.

Answer (score 0):

for swift 3.0+

```
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
 gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
```